# socket.io list of all connected

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'v create two side project. side-1 is admin side, side-2 is clients side. What I want is that, admin, can list all connected clients and see their connected status(online-ofline).Im use node.js+express.js+socket.io. help please. thanks.

Comment: Kindly post with some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get connected clients using client key and status that you are using in your socket.

Example:

Suppose to fetch online clients, you have payload with key name clients, like clients:

```
{
    { 
    id: 'client 1',
    status:'offline'
    },
    {
    id:'client 2',
    status:'online'
    }
}
```

Now you can get online clients like below,

```
const onlineClients = Object.values(io.of(namespace).connected)
    .map(socket => socket.clients)
    .filter(client => client && client.status === 'online');
```